# How to pass data from Receiver to Activity using interface?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass the data from the brodcast receiver to the activity to display it on the view using an interface, but, it's not working.
Here are my files,
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OtpPassing {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "o" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("OTP: " + msg);
    }
}
```

OtpPassing.java

```
public interface OtpPassing {
    public void onReceive(String msg);
}
```

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    String otp = getOtp(message);
                    Toast.makeText(context, otp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //This is working fine
                    OtpPassing otpPassing = new MainActivity();
                    otpPassing.onReceive(otp); //This is not working

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }

    private String getOtp(String message) {
        String otp = null;
        int index = message.indexOf("otp:");
        if(index != -1){
            int start = index + 5;
            otp = message.substring(start, start+4);
        }
        return otp;
    }
}
```

The receiver is woking(it's displaying the message on a Toast) but why is displaying the message on the screen via MainActivity not working?

Comment: Ah, you never create Activity like 'new MainActivtiy()' Activity lifecycle is managed by the Android OS.

Comment: I'm new to android, please suggest the changes to make it work

Comment: use intents http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a broadcast receiver as a data member of your activity. You register for it in onCreate and unregister in onDestroy (or onStart and onStop).

That way the receiver has a reference to the parent activity and you can do whatever.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OtpPassing {

private TextView textView;
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Access the parent activity as follows
       MainActivity.this.textView.setText("...");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //instantiate and register the receiver
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister the receiver here
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here better way (I suppose) would be to use `Android Intents`

in your receiver, something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(.....);
startactivity(intent);
```

now in your MainActivity, override `onNewIntent()`. Here check for the 'extras' you had passed from the receiver.

Please note, this might result in having multiple MainActivities running in your phone if your "older" MainActivity was not killed by the time this intent was passed via receiver. To overcome this, use 'singleTop' or similar flags in your Manifest file